# Is there connection between "Getaway" (1994) and "Real McCoy"?

Tags: production

I notice that both movies have McCoy lead character:

- Getaway (1994): Carter "Doc" McCoy and his wife Carol
- Real McCoy (1993): Karen McCoy

The names are somewhat similar (Carol/Karen) and also, importantly, both movies have Kim Basinger as a star. This lead me to think there might be some connection between two movies, almost if it is a dilogy. Is that correct or connections pure accidental?

Answer (score 2):

*The Getaway* is a remake of a Steve McQueen film released in 1972, which itself was based on a novel released in 1958. It therefore bears no relation to *The Real McCoy*. Apart from Basinger, the only other commonality I can find between the two films is that they were both distributed by Universal Studios, but Universal distribute so many films that I don't believe there's any significance to that.

The coincidence is certainly eerie, but that appears to be all it is: coincidence.